# Trimming input from stdin

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

Sometimes the strings I want are paired with strings I dont want, e.g. if I want

```
*AA*
```

sometimes it'll come in as

```
*AA* *AA* F EE*AA*F EE *AA* *AA*
```

and I don't want the "F EE" parts. Here is my code, but it doesn't work, I still get the full string like above. Any ideas why?

```
process.stdin.resume();
var seq = [];
var count = 1; 
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) { 
     (/\*AA\*/).exec(data);
     (/\*BB\*/).exec(data);
     (/\*CC\*/).exec(data);
     (/\*DD\*/).exec(data);
seq.push(data.toString('utf8')); 
   if (seq.length === count) {
      for (var i=0; i<seq.length; i++) { console.log(seq[i]); }
      seq = [];
      count++;
   }
});
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is this: a javascript _Regex_ such as your `(/\*AA\*/).exec(data)` _does not modify_ the target -- that statement matches the data against the pattern and returns the match(es). You are not assigning that returned value to anything, so executing `(/\*AA\*/).exec(data)` has no (external) effect on anything.

Comment: Ah ok. How would I return the value then?

Answer (score 0):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is good for this kind of problem. Just give the regex the `g` tag and make the wildcard non-greedy (with `?`)

```js
let str = "*AA* *BB* F EE*AA*F EE *CC* *AA*"

let seq = str.match(/\*.*?\*/g)
console.log(seq)
```

One thing that's not clear however, is how you handle partial input in the `on data` handler. For example if you receive part of a string like
`F EE*A` in one event and the other part `A*F EE` in the next event a regex is not going to match `*AA*` -- you would need to wait until you are sure you have the whole input.

Comment: Tried that, it came back with let seq = data.match(/\*.*?\*/g)
TypeError: data.match is not a function

When I made it a function I got another errorseq.push(data.toString('utf8')); 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is this: a javascript Regex such as your `(/\*AA\*/).exec(data)` does not modify the target -- that statement matches the data against the pattern and returns the match(es). You are not assigning that returned value to anything, so executing `(/\*AA\*/).exec(data)` has no (external) effect on anything.

`var found = (/\*AA\*/).exec(data)` will get the matched part, but that still doesn't modify the contents of `data`. If you're looking for all the matches, while ignoring the non-matched text, you can extract the matches from data without needing to modify it.

Start with a regex variable -- because repeated use of `.exec(s)` continues matching where it left off. A literal regex like your `/\*AA\*/` can't do that.
Here, I'm combining your expressions, and turning on the `g` "global match" option:

```
let re = /\*(AA|BB|CC|DD)\*/g;
```

Then loop as long as you find matches:

```
let re = /\*(AA|BB|CC|DD)\*/g;
let matches = [];
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(data);
    if (m) {
        // m.index can tell you where in `data` the match
        // was found, if you care.
        console.log('matched: ' + m[0]);
        // push the match into our array, to be used later.
        matches.push(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);

// now do something with the matches
```

Comment: Actually `\*[ABCD]{2}\*` will match, `*AB*`, `*AC*`, ... and any combination of these 4 charcters.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code is not returning anything, because the `.exec()` calls are not assigned to any variables and they aren't doing anything.

Another thing you can just replace all these regexes with a single **[regex](https://regex101.com/r/kcCUf9/1)**:

```
/\*(AA|BB|CC|DD)\*/g
```

And use it along with **[`String#match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** which will return an `array` of matches.

This is how should be your code:

```
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
  seq = data.match(/\*(AA|BB|CC|DD)\*/g);
  console.log(seq);
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a sample working demo:

```js
var str = "*AA* *BB* F EE*AA*F EE *CC* *AA*"

var seq = str.match(/\*(AA|BB|CC|DD)\*/g);
console.log(seq);
```